# Jquery nested sortable with sub-level restrictions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working on drag and drop of sorting of nested lists using nested sortable jquery plugin.I need particular restriction

The restrictions I need are that top-level items can be reordered but cannot be moved to a sub-level. Also sub-level items cannot be moved into top-level positions and it should not  be moved to other top-level items as a sub-item.
The sub-level items can be reordered within that top level item only.

I achieved top level restriction by setting protectRoot to true.
How we can achieve the sub-level reordering within that top level items only.

Comment: please share a code example in a jsfiddle or codepen to better help you.

Comment: see this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dq4DM/)@SandrinaPereira

Comment: first of all please review your DOM, there are <li> that don't close or close in the wrong place. Like line 6 you open a <ol> open a <li> and close </ol> without closing before the <li>

Comment: In local system i have added </li> its not working - @sandrina pereira

Comment: i don't know the plugin, but maybe your solution is to look into the documentation and see if you can make restrictions with it, e.g. allow drag only on elements with .x class or something...